# Half of screen is missing after fresh installation

Tags: display, resolution

I just installed Ubuntu on my **asus eeepc 1201hab** machine and something is off. Even during installation half of the screen would not be in use and when trailing the mouse around little patches of boxes appear. Another weird thing about this installation is that when I push my cursor all the way to the top the reemerges from the bottom of the screen. I haven't touched the **Xorg** configuration. Also took pictures to help demonstrate what I mean.

[image]

and another one

[image]

Comment: Do you any Button for the screen as `Autoset` , then please try.

Comment: Please Provide Graphic , HDD,Processor,RAM information

Answer (score 0):

Since it has an Nvidia GFX card, you should try the Nvidia propriety drivers. You can find them through System Settings > Additional Drivers.

Unless you already are using those .. Then you should have a look at the Nvidia X Server Settings tool.